# Issue related to Finding an Index of Item in List<string>

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics, listiterator

I am new to Linq..

i have `List<string>` object in my code.. i wanted to make it comma separeted, so i written following syntax

```
string commaSepNames = string.Join(",",lstNames.select(s=>s+" Customer").ToList());
```

The above syntax will result in appends with `"Customer"` in the end of name
with comma separated...

but now i want to Append Number (from 1 to Number of item in List) at the end of "Customer" like following:

John Customer1,
Ghanshyam Customer2,
Ferry Customer3,
... and so on..

how can i achive it in one Syntax line ? `without using "for loop" or "foreach loop" ??`

Thanks....

Answer (score 2):

Use the overload of [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) that gives you the index:

```
var names = lstNames.Select((s, index) => string.Format("{0} Customer{1}", s, index + 1));
string commaSepNames = string.Join(",", names);
```

If you are not using .NET 4 you need an array:

```
string commaSepNames = string.Join(",", names.ToArray());
```